# Self-similarity Matrix formation

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to compute self-similarity matrix for my chroma features.
Refer [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similarity_matrix)! for understanding self-similarity matrix.

Chroma features are vectors obtained while chord recognition for every frame.
Now since number of frames are very large (1224097) , loop has to run (n^2) times to form the matrix, n being the number of frames.
This results in bad-alloc problem.
Can anyone suggest something for this ?
Can I form the matrix with loop running some n*m times but still showing correct results ?
Or I can increase the memory or something.

Here's the code I am trying to write to form similarity matrix.
chroma_features is a vector of vectors with size equal to number of frames.

```
for(int ii=0;ii<chroma_features.size();ii++)
    {
        vector<float> tr(chroma_features.size(),0.0);
        similarity_matrix.push_back(tr);
        for(int kk=0;kk<chroma_features.size();kk++)
        {    
            float temp = 0;
            for(int jj=12;jj<24;jj++)  
            {  
                 temp += pow((chroma_features[ii][jj]-chroma_features[kk][jj]),2.0);
            }

             similarity_matrix[ii][kk] = sqrt(temp);

        }
    }
```

Problem is of storage.
My basic aim is to do this.
We compute the self-similarity matrix S = s(i,j) for the
sequence of chroma vectors using Euclidean distance. This
matrix has zeroes on the main diagonal. We normalize it
so that 0 <= s(i,j) <=  1 for any i; j. Then for each row we
preserve only M  n minimal values and set all the others
to 1 (here 0 <= M <= 1). After that we only preserve
those diagonal segments of that matrix which are parallel
to main diagonal and have length greater than or equal to k:
s(i+l;j+l) < 1|0 <= l <= k1, k1 >= k. The resulting matrix
is “sparse” in the sense that it has few elements different
from 1.
Then we recalculate the sequence of chroma vectors
Is there any other way ?